# android - images in Drawable folder and getting their id's into java

Tags: android, drawable

I'm new to development and I'm stuck at a point where I don't know what would be the best possible solution.

I have a list of 26 images saved in the drawable folder. Lets say a to z. When user clicks on the right side layout they should navigate forward and if the user clicks on the left side layout they should navigate backwards.

My issue is that these are images and their IDs as retrieved by android are random int values. I can't use that to compare which letter of alphabet should be displayed next.

How do I go about this problem?

1. If I name the images a.png, b.png, c.png... How do I retrieve the name later from the ID?
2. Will I be able to store the drawables as a key value pair using collection framework?

Comment: -first define array of drawables..then create 2 methods 1 for retrieving next drawable position in array and 1 for retrieving previous drawable position in array..then you can do according to the requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the name of your resource by

```
String resourceName = getResources().getResourceName(resId);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store all the image ids in an array.
For example,

```
int images[]=new int[]{R.id.a,R.id.b,...,R.id.z};
```

Then you need to maintain the position in array of the current image every time you navigate.
For example change position as

`pos=(pos+1)%26;`

for next image and

`pos=(pos-1)%26;`

for previous image
and then use 
`setImageResource(images[pos]);`
if its an ImageView or ImageButton, or using `getResources()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrive the ids of images in drawable folder like this...

```
 int imagekey=getResources().getIdentifier(url.toLowerCase(),"drawable",getPackageName());
```

where url is the name of the images in the drawable folder